# MATLAB column vector nulled elements

Tags: matlab

Assume we have a column vector `A`. Does anyone know what the following code line in MATLAB does?

```
A(A<= 2) = [];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `A <= 2` creates a mask of length equal to the length of original
  vector,

  whose value is `1` corresponding to values of A lesser than or equal
  to 2

  and

  `0` corresponding to values of A NOT lesser than NOR equal to 2.
  (i.e greater than 2)
- `A(A<=2)` return the values of A which satisfies the inner condition.
  i.e returns the values of `A` corresponding to which the inner values
  are `1`.
- Finally `A(A<= 2) = [];` assigns those(discussed previously)
  corresponding values to `null`.

**Example:**

```
A = randi(5,5,1)   %// creating some random column vector
A <= 2
A(A<=2) = []
```

**Output:**

```
A =

 4
 2
 3
 4
 5


ans =

 0
 1
 0
 0
 0


A =

 4
 3
 4
 5
```

You could see that, as the 2nd element is assigned to `Null` the length of the original vector `A` is reduced by `1`.